# Mech build order for Squadron TD (Starcraft 2 mod)?

Tags: starcraft-2, mods, sc2-build-order

Does anyone know a good build order for the mech race in the [Squadron TD mod](http://www.squadtd.com/) for Starcraft 2?  I've read through their forums. There's one thread for Mech and the BOs listed in there don't work.

Comment: Depends - are you defending one spawn or two?

Comment: Honestly, I'll take whatever you got.  But if you want to get specific, let's just go with one spawn.  Doesn't even have to be hybrid altho I'd prefer *some* income.

Answer (score 1):

Start with an infantry and a Peewee, then get a Tempest as soon as you can. Next upgrade the Tempest to a Leviathan as soon as you get the money. After, build a cyborg as soon as possible, then you can start to produce more scvs. Upgrade the cyborg to Krogoth, and start getting Neotanks and upgrading them to Doomsday machines. All the while steadily get scvs.